# Sincronizacion de hora exacta con php

Tags: php, laravel

tengo el siguiente inconveniente: tengo un proveedor que tiene un Servicio Soap (uno de varios) al cual debo enviar un fichero con cierta información, en la que se incluye la fecha exacta en la que se envia el fichero, suponiendo que es el dia y hora para enviar 2022-05-11T12:00:00.123 (doce en punto con 123 milisegundos) el fichero, entonces si lo envío, hay un desfase de tiempo con el servidor, ya que este me retorna que el valor no es valido (hay una serie de procesos para mandar la fecha, se adjunta o concadena otra información pero que no cambia), entonces dado ese error no puedo subir o mandar al servicio el fichero...

Mi duda es ¿Hay alguna forma de que pueda sincronizar la hora de mi equipo local con la hora del servidor del proveedor?, el proveedor tiene un servicio soap que devuelve la hora y fecha que manejan en el formato YYYY:MM:DDThh:mm:ss.sss, y quisiera tomar esa información y configurar mi equipo o php para que trabaje con esa hora ya sincronizada y pueda mandar la información, existe un retraso cuando se consulta al servicio soap.

El error me da cuando el servicio toma el fichero y verifica la "fecha completa con tiempo" y lo compara con su hora interna

php 8.1.3 - laravel 9 - ubuntu 20.04

Edit:
Como llamo a la fecha que ofrece el servidor a partir de su soap

```
$dateTimeFull=(new ServicioSincronizacionDatosController)->getSyncDateTime()["fechaHora"];
```

como obtengo mi hora y fecha local:

```
$myDate=Utilities::getDateTime();

public static function getDateTime(){
        $dateTime=date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s");
        $milis=explode(".",microtime(true))[1];
        $milis=strval($milis*1000);
        $res="";
        for($j=0;$j<=2;$j++){
            $res=$res.$milis[$j];
        }
        $dateTime=$dateTime.".$res" ;
        return $dateTime;       
    }
```

Como ejemplo, dejo lo que me devuelve cada uno:

Local:

```
"2022-05-11T14:26:28.346"
```

Servicio sopa del proveedor:

```
"2022-05-11T14:26:30.170"
```

Comment: el desface de tempo que te sale es por que demora X segundos/milisegundos en realizar la conexión y el envió de datos, cuando llegue la informacion jamás será idéntico ... lo que intentas hacer no tiene sentido ... cual es el objetivo de intentar tener dos fechas idénticas, intentas comprobar algo o validar o certificar???

Comment: por otro lado he visto que tus post no están incluyendo código y en este caso hace falta ver y saber para que intentas implementar una sincronización de fecha... votare para cerrar esta pregunta hasta que plantees con ejemplos tus hipotéticas ideas ...

Comment: ¿Te dice el proveedor en qué zona horaria trabaja? Lo usual es que lo hagan en UTC, pero en todo caso, sin esa información y sin saber cómo estás consumiendo la API, es muy difícil encontrar el problema.

Comment: ah bueno, es que comentarte, es para facturación electronica, resulta que la fecha es utilizada para para generar su numero de facturación, y bueno, el servicio que consumo, valida la información de la cabecera de la factura (incluye el numero de facturación), y el error que me da es basicamente es que me rechaza el archivo por que el codigo o numeración de la factura que envío, varia con respecto al codigo o numeracion de factura que espera el servicio

Comment: Mauricio, si, esta en UTC

Comment: por eso mismo, creo que se debe sincronizar la hora del servidor, con mi equipo local, ya que haciendo consultas y viendo las horas de mi local con la del servicio llamado sincronizarhora, hay una variacion de entre 0.3 segundos hasta 1.5 segundos aproximadamente (segun mis calculos), lo cual hace variar en la generacion del codigo o numero de la factura

Comment: Más bien, cada servidor debería sincronizar su hora usando NTP.

Comment: me parece que no hay que sincronizar nada... 
yo trabaje facturación electrónica con ecuador ...
y lo que hacia falta era usar la misma informacion de la cabecera que devolvía el servicio api: no tiene por que ser idéntica a la hora de impresión ... ya que el consumo de la api dependiendo de la demanda puede llevar varios segundos...

Comment: Eso intenté, usar la información que me devolvia sobre la fecha el servidor, y mandarlo en la factura, pero no me acepta